# How to make an autocomplete that get's "finer" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I configured my autocomplete feature like this (python, but shouldn't matter):

```
autocomplete_filter = token_filter(
        'autocomplete_tokenizer',
        type='edge_ngram',
        min_gram=3,
        max_gram=15,
        tokenizer='standard',
    )
analyzers['autocomplete'] = analyzer(
    'autocomplete',
    type='custom',
    tokenizer='standard',
    filter=["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", autocomplete_filter]
)
```

This does a great job. E.g. when i have "alltime" and "allrounder" in my documents, it returns both.

However, when I query "allr" (note the r), I only want to have "allrounder" in my results, but still get both.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: What do you query for in your example?

Comment: What do u mean? I have a field like this: `completion = Text(analyzer=analyzers['autocomplete'], fielddata=True)` and I query with  "match" and e.g. 'all' and 'allrou' and i want all results on the previous and only allorunder on the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be `prefix`, not `match`.